# Setting up the `regex.h` library on Windows with VS Code

Tags: c, gdb, vscode-tasks

I've been trying to get the `regex.h` library to work all day, but it's not working. (*Here are my VS Code workspace configurations: https://github.com/EnderCommunity/Murmur/tree/main/.vscode* - ***all the compiler info are here***)

This is the file that I was trying to get the regex library to work with:
https://github.com/EnderCommunity/Murmur/blob/main/compiler/libraries/regex/reg.h

I tried to include the library normally, but it returns an error:
[image]

And I tried to include [this library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/regex/2.7/regex-2.7-bin.zip/download), but it returns some compiling errors:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

Starting build...
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe" -g C:\Users\adels\Desktop\EnderCommunity\Projects\Murmur\compiler\start.c -o C:\Users\adels\Desktop\EnderCommunity\Projects\Murmur\compiler\start.exe
C:\Users\adels\AppData\Local\Temp\ccifSq1r.o: In function `regChk':
C:/Users/adels/Desktop/EnderCommunity/Projects/Murmur/compiler/libraries/regex/reg.h:15: undefined reference to `__imp_regcomp'
C:/Users/adels/Desktop/EnderCommunity/Projects/Murmur/compiler/libraries/regex/reg.h:22: undefined reference to `__imp_regexec'
C:/Users/adels/Desktop/EnderCommunity/Projects/Murmur/compiler/libraries/regex/reg.h:33: undefined reference to `__imp_regerror'
C:/Users/adels/Desktop/EnderCommunity/Projects/Murmur/compiler/libraries/regex/reg.h:40: undefined reference to `__imp_regfree'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

**So the way that I included this library might be wrong!** What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) will fix this, it comes with all the necessary libraries for C.